# Vlookup to display only when button is clicked and clear when a new word is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button coded that will randomly select a word from a list. I have another button that uses the vlookup function to show the definition of the random word selected. When I hit new word it selects a word and automatically displays the definition before the definition button is clicked.

How can I get the definition button (vlookup coding) to only show the definition when the button is clicked?

```
 Sub Definition3()
Range("J3") = "=VLookup(B2, Sheet1!A:B, 2, False)"
 End Sub
```

Comment: We are going to need a little more detail. Expand on your question based on [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the value of the cell to empty when you click the first button?

```
Sub Word()
Range("J3").ClearContents
' or Range("J3")=""

' then your code to fetch the new word to show

 End Sub
```

HTH,

B